# Searching for information about Pauline Kramer an Orphan born 1913 in NYC

Tags: vital-records

I am looking for information about my mother Pauline Kramer - in an orphanage or convent born in New York City 1913. She lived there unil 1920 and then was sent to  Green Bay Wisconsin to live with the Sisters of Our Lady of Charity 1920-1930

Comment: As it stands this question is too broad for our site -- please review the guidance at https://genealogy.stackexchange.com/help/dont-ask and break this into a number of questions, starting with the one of most importance to you). Do you have her details for the 1920 census, for example?

Comment: Hi, welcome to G&FH.SE! What information do you want to know first? Some guidance on how to ask a good question is here: https://genealogy.stackexchange.com/help/how-to-ask